# 'v' that sounds like 'b'

Tags: pronunciation

https://youtu.be/zUMnAqJEfT0?t=2133
Does he say "firstobol" or "firstovol"? What do I do if I hear speakers say "b" instead of "v"?

Comment: Kate has the answer below, but I want to point out that native English speakers clearly distinguish between "b" and "v" but some other languages, notably Spanish, do not. If I heard someone mixing b and v sounds in English, I might wonder if they were Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

He says "*First of all*". *Firstobol* is not an English word.